# Worklight Server Local Development, some the WL.Server calls are unavailable or not working properly

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, ibm-mobilefirst

We are writing a basic adapter and attempting to call a published API but the API is not following the expected contract.  We are simply calling the API 'var request = WL.Server.getClientRequest();' and this  call is returning null but in some cases it returns the J2EE request object.

We are working with worklight studio: 6.1.0.01-20140427-1450

And this only occurs for local development on a Windows x86-64 bit machine.    To recreate the issue, we  deploy the adapter on the server and then execute the "Invoke Worklight Procedure" option within Eclipse.  The default browser launches (latest version of chrome) and when running the adapter, the call to getClientRequest is null.

Eclipse Kepler - version=4.3.2

Java 1.6

Why would this call return null?

We have done clean on the server, rebuild the project but this did not correct the problem.

Related:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI18296

Comment: What are the cases that it Does return the expected result?

Comment: It seems to be machine/developer-station based.  E.g. machine1 with the same Eclipse configuration may not receive this error.  Machine2 will receive this error.  Initially machine2 did not receive the error but now we can't get past it.  There isn't much difference between the two machines, one developer may add custom configurations etc.

Comment: We considered a couple of different things.  We deleted the built-in liberty server.  Delete the generate WAR file in /bin directory.  We were trying things that would clean-up server and build environment.  But both machines will have the same Worklight installation and Eclipse version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This API will indeed return null in case procedure is invoked from a WL Studio. The reason is that studio emulates client and the original request never forwarded to adapter layer. This is done in order to automatically bypass wl_antiXSRF realm. You can either

1. Remove /dev/ part of the URL used to invoke adapter procedure. In this case you'll have to either manually do wl_antiXSRF authentication or disable it for dev purposes
2. Create a simple WL App that invokes your procedure and use it from a web browser.

Comment: We don't have wl_antiXSRF enabled through our configuration.  Also, some worklight studio machines do work properly.  The WL.Server.getClientRequest is server-side adapter code, why would it return null?  I was thinking this is the standard J2EE Request object, it seems like there would be a flaw if I can't get request information like user-agent etc.

Comment: Also, we don't get this error if do the following:  If using Worklight Studio's > Invoke Adapter procedure, remove
the "/dev/" from the opened URL window:

http://{serverIP}:{serverPort}/{projectName}/dev/invoke?adapter=
{adapterName}&procedure={procedureName}&parameters={params}

To:

http://{serverIP}:{serverPort}/{projectName}/invoke?adapter={ada
pterName}&procedure={procedureName}&parameters={params}

Comment: This is exactly what I've told you. When you're using /dev/ you're going through a special dev-only adapter preview servlet which might prevent access to httprequest. When you're not going through /dev/ you're working with real adapter invocation service and everything will be functional.

Comment: Why would one machine have '/dev/' act properly but the other not?   At least what I have seen, the issue is machine/configuration based.